Make property optional if generic type is undefined
Is it possible to make a property optional based on a generic type being undefined?
For example, say I have the following type that accepts a couple of possibly-undefined generic type parameters:
type Data<A = undefined, B = undefined> = {
    a: A;
    b: B;
}

I'm trying to make property a optional (i.e. a:? A) when the generic type A is undefined. Likewise, property b should be optional when the generic type B is undefined.
Some test cases to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.
// Should compile
// type `A` is undefined so property "a" should be optional
const test1: Data<undefined, string> = { b: 'B' };

// Should error
// type `B` is not undefined so `b` should be required
const test2: Data<number, string> = { a: 1 };

// Should compile
// Types`A` & `B` are not undefined
// so properties `a` and `b` are required and present
const test3: Data<number, string> = { a: 1, b: 'B' };


Definitely possible with a simple conditional type, but what would be the use case? Looks like a XY problem to me.

@Blackhole The use case is purely for convenience. If a property can only be undefined, why bother specifying it? Instead, it's more convenient to make it optional, defaulting to undefined.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz This is suitable for my small example, but it becomes a lot harder to implement if you have multiple generic type parameters. Consider this example - I could use your approach to cover every possible combination of undefined/defined generic types, but it would quickly get tricky to maintain. Would it be possible to utilize Mapping Modifiers here instead?

Could you [edit] the question to make it clear what you're looking for? I'm now sort of thinking you want something like type UndefinableToOptional<T> which converts T into a type where all properties that accept undefined are now optional.  Like this playground link shows. Is that what you want? If so then I'll write up an answer, once you confirm, and once you edit the question to make that clear. If not then what am I missing now?

@jcalz That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the solution. If you get time to write up an answer that would be great. Thanks for your help!

You can write your own utility type like UndefinableToOptional<T> which turns all properties which accept undefined into optional properties.  Note that there's no way to "conditionally" turn on and off mapping modifiers like ? inside a single mapped type. This is requested in microsoft/TypeScript#32562. The closest we can get is to break T into the part we want to be optional and the part we want to be required and then intersect them together:
type UndefinableToOptional<T> =
    { [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? K : never]?: Exclude<T[K], undefined> } &
    { [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K] }

That definition uses the filtering functionality of key remapping to act like either Pick or Omit.
Once we have that we can define your Data type
type Data<A = undefined, B = undefined> =
    UndefinableToOptional<{
        a: A;
        b: B;
    }>

and test out how it behaves:
type X = Data<undefined, string>;
/* type X = {
    a?: never;
} & {
    b: string;
} */

type Y = Data<number, string>;
/* type Y = {} & {
    a: number;
    b: string;
} */

And just to check, let's throw some other types at it:
type Z = UndefinableToOptional<{
    a: number,
    b: string | undefined,
    c?: boolean, 
    readonly d: Date | undefined, 
    readonly e: null
}>
/* type Z = {
    b?: string;
    c?: boolean;
    readonly d?: Date;
} & {
    a: number;
    readonly e: null;
} */

Looks good.  Intersections of object types are equivalent to single object types (and if it's important, you could rewrite UndefinableToOptional<T> to result in a single object type... you could even make sure the property order doesn't change. But those are more complicated implementations for questionable benefit).
Playground link to code
